# Bluetooth Low Energy application in Visual Studio C++ for image sharing. Which tools should I use?

Tags: android, c++, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to develop a C++ application on Windows 10 (using Visual Studio 2017) capable of looking for nearby mobile devices and sending data (images) via Bluetooth. I'm new to Bluetooth applications, but from what I understand, the best solution is to use BLE and make the computer a GATT server.

For this purpose, I'm quite confused about which tool I should use in order to start creating my application, since most of the libraries I have found online are outdated or poorly documented ([libblepp](https://github.com/edrosten/libblepp), [gattlibpp](https://github.com/psychogenic/gattlibpp), [bluetoe](https://github.com/TorstenRobitzki/bluetoe)).
I've also found this [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server) but I don't understand if this is what I should use and I don't know how to include it in my project neither.
Has anybody had some experience with this and could provide me some hints concerning the right tool to use, in order to get started with my project?

On the other side, I would like to develop a mobile app using [**Flutter**](https://flutter.dev/) capable of receiving the image and reading the data sent by the computer. [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) looks like the best option to go with.

**Edit:** The idea for the application is the following: the computer runs an application that generates various frames. In the meanwhile, it constantly scans for nearby devices and, whenever a user makes a request, it sends the current output image to the device that makes the request.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Asking for library, framework or tool recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: All modern smartphones have build-in support for receiving files by Bluetooth. This called OBEX (Object Push Profile) and it is Classic Bluetooth feature (OBEX runs above RFCOMM). So all you need is just a classic Bluetooth API and OBEX implementation. You can try Bluetooth Framework (www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm)

Comment: Windows 10 already supports to [share things with nearby devices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-things-with-nearby-devices-in-windows-0efbfe40-e3e2-581b-13f4-1a0e9936c2d9#WindowsVersion=Windows_10). Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Risto Because I need the application to process this automatically, i.e. I need it to constantly scan and look for nearby devices, and create a new connection whenever a user makes a new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows API is what you should use if you write a C++ application for Windows. That will be the best supported option. If you happen to find some library that also does BLE it will probably just be a wrapper around the Windows API.

Unfortunately these APIs use the WinRT architecture which is not the easiest to set up but should work fine once you've managed to set up the environment.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any experience with these APIs? Am I forced to create a new project as a Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT) or I can also use a standard Visual C++ blank project as well? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#visual-studio-support-for-cwinrt-xaml-the-vsix-extension-and-the-nuget-package

Comment: You could create a new WinRT project, write down the configuration and try to apply those for your other project.